# Return arguments of nested function in R

Tags: r, function

I want to take user input, call a function using that input, then print the actual arguments to the screen.

```
fitfun <- function(dataset = Auto, outcome = 1, predictor = 3) {

    fits <- lm(dataset[,outcome] ~ dataset[,predictor])

     summary.lm(fits)$call

}
```

The output of this code is:

```
> fitfun()
lm(formula = dataset[, outcome] ~ dataset[, predictor])
```

What I want is:

```
> fitfun()
lm(formula = Auto[, 1] ~ Auto[, 3])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some regex tinkering on the `summary(fits)$call` text, try this:

```
fitfun <- function(dataset = mtcars, outcome = 1, predictor = 3) {

  fits <- lm(dataset[,outcome] ~ dataset[,predictor])

  call <- paste(summary(fits)$call, collapse = " ")

  call <- gsub("dataset", deparse(substitute(dataset)), call)

  call <- gsub("outcome", outcome, call)

  call <- gsub("predictor", predictor, call)

  return(call)
}
```

Comment: Great function, does exactly what I wanted on its own. However, I have it nested within another function and when I call to `fitfun` from within that function it will still print "dataset" as "dataset." With a little tweaking to my parent function, using your function, I was able to get outcome and predictor to print with their actual values. Thanks!